# Laravel Routing - Separate some routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a route defined as:

```
Route::resource('item', 'ItemController');
```

What I want to do is put some of these routes, particularly `edit` and `delete` inside a group.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role']], function() {

    Route::resource('item', 'ItemController', ['only' => ['edit', 'delete']]);
}
```

This doesn't work, though. Do I have to define each route one by one then? Or is there a better solution to this?

EDIT:

I'm sorry, but it seems I did not ask the question properly. So let me make some clarifications here.

I have a basic `auth` user which can create and view `items`. What I don't want it to do is edit and delete.

I then also have a `role` user which do everything `auth` can do AND edit and delete `items`.

So basically, regular authorized users can have SOME access to `items` while `role` users have COMPLETE access.

The current code seems to give `role` users ONLY edit and delete functionalities and no view or create.

To make it even more clearer, here's what my actual route looks like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function()
{
    Route::resource('items', 'SitesController');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['role']], function() {
        Route::resource('item', 'ItemController', ['only' => ['edit', 'delete']]);
    });
});
```

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

Comment: You want to assign the middleware only to edit and delete?

Comment: Yes @michael, basically, everyone can view/create an `item` but only users with a certain role can edit or delete them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I may just didn't understand the question. Can you show the middleware we are talking about please?

Comment: Did my other comment get deleted? Weird. What I want to do is have regular authorized users to have access to `create`, `index`, and `store`. While I want "role" users to have all that plus `edit` and `delete`.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Then I think the middleware should be assigned like I said and should fail if the user isn't an role user.

Comment: Something like `if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            // Redirect...
        }

        return $next($request);`

Comment: How do you define it in the construct though so that, `auth` users can access create, index, and store and `role` users can access all plus edit and delete.

Answer (score 0):

The code above will work, you just named the action incorrectly. You should have used **destroy** instead of **delete**. Try the following code:

```
Route::resource('item', 'ItemController');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role']], function() {
  Route::resource('item', 'ItemController', ['only' => ['edit', 'destroy']]);
});
```

You can run **php artisan route:list** to verify. You should see **role** middleware enabled in 2 of your routes.